# Stop CSS hierarchy

Tags: html, css, inheritance, css-selectors, hierarchy

I have a hierarchy as follows:

```
<div class="outer">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p><a>Link</a></p>

    <div class="inner">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
        <p><a>Link</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the elements within the `outer` div to be styled in a certain way, and the elements within the `inner` div to be styled in another.

However, I don't want to have to pollute my rules for `inner` elements with resets for every property the `outer` rules defined.

In the following example, I want to avoid `margin: 0px`. Note that, of course, my stylesheet is much more complex and resets would be significantly more numerous and annoying.

```
outer a { margin: 5px; }
inner a { margin: 0px; color: orange; }
```

My initial reflex is to use the direct child selector `>`, but that becomes cumbersome for, say, links, strong, spans, etc.

The following example:

```
outer > a { color: orange; }
```

Would not style:

```
<div class="outer"><p><a>Link</a></p></div>
<div class="outer"><strong><a>Link</a></strong></div>
<div class="outer"><ul><li><a>Link</a></li></ul></div>
<div class="outer"><table><tr><td><a>Link</a></td></tr></table></div>
...
```

I need to find some other way of either

- Breaking the hierarchy at `inner`, without explicitly defining resets.
- Limiting the scope of the outer styles to stop at `inner`.

Is this possible?
Note that rearranging my HTML structure is not possible in the present case.

Comment: Since you say rearranging your HTML is not possible, is `.inner` guaranteed to be a child of `.outer` only, and not nested anywhere else?

Comment: @BoltClock: Sadly, no, `.inner` might appear outside `.outer`. Sorry, the names are indeed misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is CSS3 selectors an option for you? if yes, may this trick helps:

**CSS:**

```
.outer>:not(div) a { color: orange; }
```

**EDIT:**

```
.outer > a, .outer > :not(.inner) a { color: orange; }
```

**[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ikajep/2/edit)** demo

Comment: That does have the shortcoming of not styling, say `<div class="outer"><a>Link</a></div>`, doesn't it?

Comment: `.outer>:not(.inner)` would apply to all direct children of `.outer` that do not have the class `.inner`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjM6y/). Tested in Chrome 22, IE 9, FF 13.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, Nice, but what if `.outer` div contains more than one element? should the headers or paragraphs be selected?

Comment: @HashemQolami They are. The selector is for *all* direct children (`>`) that are not `.inner`. Children of direct children that are not in `.inner` could be obtained using `.outer>:not(.inner) *`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `:not` selector:

```
.outer > *:not(.inner) *
```